# My orginal buttons won't show up but my hovers will?

Tags: css, button, web, hover, hyperlink

On my website, my buttons for me aren't showing up. But, when I put my mouse over them the hover images do show up. Do they show for you? Let me know.

Link: http://cascadestudios.webstarts.com/terms_of_service.html

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake on css for background image:

```
.layicon a#semi{display: block;width:138px;height:27px;background:url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/semi.png) no-repeat;}.
```

you added an "Enter" or \n in front of url property

Try to open your website with chrome and then inspect your element.
chrome will show that your background setting is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

This is the css for your navicon

```
.navicon a#terms {
    display: block;
    height: 27px;
    width: 138px;
}
```

When you hover, you add the background image.

```
.navicon a#terms:hover {
    background: url("http://icpy.webs.com/button/Terms0.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0     transparent;
}
```

You need to add a background image to the actual link.

```
.navicon a#terms {
    display: block;
    height: 27px;
    width: 138px;
    background: url("http://icpy.webs.com/button/Terms0.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0     transparent;
}
```